# Как получить ссылку в Python

Tags: python, парсер, youtube

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста:
Есть такой код

```
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch

videosSearch = VideosSearch('NoCopy', limit = 1)
a = (videosSearch.result())
print (a)
```

Выдает такой результат:

```
{'result': [{'type': 'video', 'id': 'ABuNwLP-z9o', 'title': ' Top 50 NoCopyRightSounds | Best of NCS | Most viewed ! Gaming Music | The Best of All Time | 2021', 'publishedTime': '3 years ago', 'duration': '3:00:24', 'viewCount': {'text': '11,333,842 views', 'short': '11M views'}, 'thumbnails': [{'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ABuNwLP-z9o/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCOgCEMoBSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLC0rl3DGDwIvQs3ADcVp40EyQmhDw', 'width': 360, 'height': 202}, {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ABuNwLP-z9o/hq720.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEcCNAFEJQDSFXyq4qpAw4IARUAAIhCGAFwAcABBg==&rs=AOn4CLBUWW_Gz6kYwRcNJ9yudEipM2idwQ', 'width': 720, 'height': 404}], 'richThumbnail': {'url': 'https://i.ytimg.com/an_webp/ABuNwLP-z9o/mqdefault_6s.webp?du=3000&sqp=CPq37ZIG&rs=AOn4CLAdB9gh2LOvQwf1Sx6E58AYfJXuCw', 'width': 320, 'height': 180}, 'descriptionSnippet': [{'text': 'Best of NCS | The Best of All Time Track list: 01. 0:00 Alan Walker - Fade 02. 4:20 Alan Walker - Spectre 03. 8:07 Different Heaven\xa0...'}], 'channel': {'name': 'Freeme NCS Music', 'id': 'UCG0SzK_t4-Ylf1yZq9Xmi_g', 'thumbnails': [{'url': 'https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLSHgpuCBptK0p-AbLOrcb-Utpxr4zDJvPAddlf2=s68-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj', 'width': 68, 'height': 68}], 'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCG0SzK_t4-Ylf1yZq9Xmi_g'}, 'accessibility': {'title': ' Top 50 NoCopyRightSounds | Best of NCS | Most viewed ! Gaming Music | The Best of All Time | 2021 by Freeme NCS Music 3 years ago 3 hours 11,333,842 views', 'duration': '3 hours, 24 seconds'}, 'link': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABuNwLP-z9o', 'shelfTitle': None}]}
```

Как можно сделать так что бы выдавала только последнюю ссылку?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Если предполагать, что нужна одна ссылка из запроса и что всегда будут данные, то вот так

```
print(a['result'][0]['link']) # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABuNwLP-z9o
```

вместо

```
print (a)
```

Но реальность обычно сложнее и надо еще озаботиться проверками. Напишите ниже в комментарии, если будут возникать ошибки.

Если больше одной записи, то

```
for record in a['result']:
    print(record['link'])
```